# I somehow put a dotted square on my artboard in Illustrator, how do I remove it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've mistakenly pressed a random combination of keys and a dotted square appeared on my artboard, now I don't know what is it or how to remove it. It's not selectable at all, it's just overlapping in front of everything.
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Go to "Window" and then "Guide" and click on "Clear guide".

Comment: and may be your issue is different you can try this on also.: go to window>hide artboard